# Trouble integrating USDT TRC20 payment for Telegram Subscription Bot

Tags: python, blockchain, cryptocurrency, tron

I am currently working on building a Telegram Subscription Bot that allows users to pay in USDT TRC20 to join private channels/groups. However, I am facing challenges with integrating USDT TRC20 payment into my bot.

I believe that I need to create a unique address for each user to identify their payments, and I also need to implement a timer in my script to periodically check if users have made the required payments.

I have searched extensively on the internet but couldn't find any suitable solutions that avoid using full payment gateways like Paydi9, Coinbase, or Coinremitter. I was hoping to find a similar solution on GitHub, but unfortunately, I haven't had any success.

My main challenge is in creating a USDT TRC20 address with private keys for each user, and then checking for payments and sending the USDT to my main address. I am assuming that I will need to use a service like https://www.trongrid.io, but I am quite clueless about the implementation details.

Can anyone provide guidance or suggestions on how to effectively integrate USDT TRC20 payment into my Telegram Subscription Bot without relying on full payment gateways? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!